# Angular 2 CLI and Underscore

Tags: angular, underscore.js, angular-cli

I am trying to include "underscore": "^1.8.3" using the current Angular 2 CLI
and I get this error Cannot find module 'underscore'.

This is how I try to import it.
import * as _ from 'underscore';

I went online to look for a solution which there where many from last year by including it in the system-config.js and typings.json files. However I do not have these files in my project. I guess they are no longer provided by the current Angular 2 CLI.

Is there a solution for importing underscore with the new Angular 2 CLI?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install that libraries `typings` definitions in previous versions, if you want to use an `JS` library in `TypeScript`.

In newer version of `TypeScript` uses `@types` system. So now you don't need to install typings manually, you can just write this. For first install

```
npm install -g typescript@next
```

And then

```
npm install --save underscore
npm install --save @types/underscore
```

For more you can see in the [**The Future of Declaration Files**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/).

Comment: This method worked for me! Issue closed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to add to your library extern project you need to follow these steps:

1. `npm install --save jQuery` or `npm install --save bootstrap` or `npm install --save underscore`
2. You need to adding  the path of the new library to your angular-cli.json file inside the scripts array.

   ```
   scripts : [
      '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
      '../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      '../node_modules/underscore/underscore.js'
   ]
   ```

   3 (optional). 
   if you need to insert css as well just insert the css path at your angular-cli.json at styles array.